# Does Infinispan TransactionManagerLookup support WebSphere Liberty?

Tags: ejb, websphere-liberty, infinispan

I was trying to deploy a Java EE application within a WebSphere Liberty BASE server in a Windows environment, within this application I'm using Infinispan as my transactional cache. I faced the following issue when the application tried to access the transactional cache.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create a transactional context without a valid Transaction instance.
    at org.infinispan.context.impl.TransactionalInvocationContextFactory.createInvocationContext(TransactionalInvocationContextFactory.java:63)
    at org.infinispan.context.impl.TransactionalInvocationContextFactory.createInvocationContext(TransactionalInvocationContextFactory.java:57)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.lock(CacheImpl.java:995)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.lock(CacheImpl.java:980)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.EncoderCache.lock(EncoderCache.java:307)
```

Below are the features I have used and my server.xml looks something like the below,

```
<featureManager>
        <feature>javaee-8.0</feature>
        <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<transaction
        totalTranLifetimeTimeout="300s"
        propogatedOrBMTTranLifetimeTimeout="300s"
        heuristicRetryWait="0"
        acceptHeuristicHazard="false" 
        recoverOnStartup="true"
        waitForRecovery="false"/>
```

Also, this is the way I configured the Infinispan transactional cache template.

```
<local-cache-configuration name="local-txn-cache-template">
            <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED" acquire-timeout="15000" concurrency-level="1"></locking>
            <transaction mode="NON_XA" locking="PESSIMISTIC"
                         transaction-manager-lookup="org.infinispan.transaction.lookup.GenericTransactionManagerLookup"
                         complete-timeout="15000"/>
        </local-cache-configuration>
```

Other than that my application getting the following failures in the Infinispan transaction manager lookup stage.

[stack trace for Infinispan transaction manager lookup failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyDjA.png)

Can anyone verify whether Infinispan supports transactional caching with WebSphere Liberty?